# Is there aws region latency test tool?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a tool to test the latency of specific regions?

I have tried the cloudping.cloud but it only test the latency of my local network to other regions.

Is there a way to test latency between Austria to Zurich region? Or Austria to Milan Region?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you don't want to test the latency of your local network to regions, are you looking for the latency *between* AWS regions? We can't answer that as it depends on things like VPCs etc.

Comment: Third-party measures of inter-region latencies at https://www.cloudping.co/grid and https://www.concurrencylabs.com/img/posts/9-choose-region-wisely/ec2-s3-1mb-table.png